# $f(n) = f(2n)$, and $f(2n + 1) = f(n) + 1$, find expression of such $f$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

The question is

a. $f(n) = f(2n)$

b. $f(2n + 1) = f(n) + 1$,

with $f(1)=1$, find expression of such $f$ that defined on positive integers

Got an initial idea about the pattern but find the difficulty to find the exact form. It's related to exponent of 2 (obviously). the number of times it can be expressed as addition of 2 exponents

for example, for $13 = 2^3+2^2+2^0, f(13) = 3$

and $16=2^4, f(16)=1; 15 = 2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0, f(15)=4$

in other words, it's the sum of all digits in its binary form, right? if so what's the formula of it.

during such time as I wrote my thoughts down, it seems I come up with a formula

$$a-\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \lfloor a/2^i\rfloor.$$
which seems to be the answer to the question

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$? Are they both positive integers?

Comment: @VTand yes thanks for mentioning I forgot to add it.

Comment: If you have a formula, why don't you try induction?

Comment: You don't need to describe the formula only using symbols. You could say "$f(n)$ is the digit sum of the binary representation". If you really wanted, you could say "If $ n = (a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots a_n )_2$, then $f(n) = \sum a_i$.". $\quad$ And yes, that's the correct description of the function. How have you tried to prove it?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I tried to prove it with induction, but runs into difficulty dealing with floor function

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your suggestion! I'm new with math description. I tried to prove it with induction just now, but ran into difficulty dealing with floor function which I'm not really familiar with.

Comment: Try doing the induction using words not just symbols. Just write it out, and see how far you can get. "EG If n=2k is even, then f2k) is equal to .... so by the induction hypothesis ... hence we have shown that f(2k) is the digit sum of the binary representation".

Comment: After this problem you might want to check out Legendre's formula which is related to what you've worked out in your representation.

Comment: @CalvinLin this function is often referred to as $\operatorname{bitcount}(n)$

Comment: @Samual If $a_k$ are the binary digits of $\,a = \overline{a_na_{n-1}\dots a_1a_0}\,$ then $a = \sum 2^k a_k$ and $a_k = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor \bmod 2$ so you have an explicit formula for each bit, and you can simply sum them up. Are you looking for some kind of "better" formula, and "better" in what sense?

Comment: For curiosity, I found back a nice result about the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{bitcount(n)}{n(n+1)}=2\ln(2)$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4025339/399263 where I used explicitely the formulas proposed here for $f$.

Comment: @dxiv I would really like to see other f expression as well. The major issue I'm currently stuck is how to rigorously prove the result.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308977/fn-f2n-and-f2n-1-fn-1-find-expression-of-such-f?noredirect=1#comment8977529_4308977), let the binary representation of $a$ be $\,\overline{a_na_{n-1}\dots a_1a_0}\,$ with $\,a_k \in \{0,1\}\,$, then $\,a = \sum_{k \ge 0} 2^k a_k\,$ and $\,a_k = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor \bmod 2\,$, so the sum of binary digits can be written as $\,\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor \bmod 2\right)\,$.

Using the identity $\,n \bmod 2 = n - 2 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\,$ leads to the form in OP's question:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor \bmod 2\right) &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor - 2 \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor \right)
\\ &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor \right) - \sum_{k \ge 0} \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor
\\ &= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^0}\right\rfloor - \cancel{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^1}\right\rfloor} + \cancel{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^1}\right\rfloor} - \bcancel{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^2}\right\rfloor}  + \bcancel{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^2}\right\rfloor} - \dots\right) - \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{k}}\right\rfloor
\\ &= a - \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{k}}\right\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By successive division by $2$ you get:

- $f(2^nx)=f(2^{n-1}x)=\cdots=f(x)$
- $f(2^n(2x+1))=f(2x+1)=f(x)+1$

Also we will need $f(0)$:

- $f(1)=f(1+2\times 0)=f(0)+1$ and since $f(1)=1$ then $f(0)=0$

Let's write $n$ in its binary form $n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^M 2^{\alpha_i}$ with $\alpha_i>\alpha_j$ for $i>j$

Said otherwise $n$ has $M$ bits set to $1$.

Then notice that $n=2^{\alpha_1}(1+\sum\limits_{i=2}^M 2^{\alpha_i-\alpha_1})=2^{\alpha_1}(1+2\underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=2}^M 2^{\alpha_i-\alpha_1-1}}_x)$

Since $\alpha_i>\alpha_1\iff \alpha_i\ge \alpha_1+1\iff \beta_i=\alpha_i- \alpha_1-1\ge 0$ then $x=\sum\limits_{i=2}^M 2^{\beta_i}$

And you have your induction on the value of $M$ i.e. $f(n)=f(x)+1$ with $x<n$ having $M-1$ bits set to $1$.

The process terminates when the next number is $0$ aka. $M-M=0$ bits set to $1$, which corresponds to $f(n)=\underbrace{f(0)}_0+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_\text{M terms}=M=\operatorname{bitcount}(n)$.

---

Here is an alternative approach we will show that $f$ and bitcount coincide on all integers:

Let define $g(n)=f(n)-\operatorname{bitcount}(n)$

It is not difficult to show that $\operatorname{bitcount}$ obeys the same relations than $f$, indeed a multiplication by $2$ just shift all the bits to the left and add a zero to the right, this doesn't change the bitcount so $\operatorname{bitcount}(2n)=\operatorname{bitcount}(n)$. And for $2n+1$ it is not a zero we add to the right but a one, so the bit count is raised by $1$ and $\operatorname{bitcount}(2n+1)=\operatorname{bitcount}(2n)+1=\operatorname{bitcount}(n)+1$.

We have $g(0)=g(1)=0$ to start our induction and we will assume it is true up to $n$.

- $n=2p$ then $g(n+1)=f(2p+1)-\operatorname{bitcount}(2p+1)=(f(p)+1)-(\operatorname{bitcount}(p)+1)=g(p)=0$ by induction since $p<n$.
- $n=2p+1$ then $g(n+1)=f(2p+2)-\operatorname{bitcount}(2p+2)=f(p+1)-\operatorname{bitcount}(p+1)=g(p+1)=0$ by induction since $p+1<n$.

This terminates our induction and we conclude $g(n)=0$ for all $n$.

---

Finally here is a computational expression of $f$ (& is the bitwise AND operator):

$f(n)=\min\{\ i\mid u_i=0\text{ where } u_0=n,\ u_{i+1}=u_i \mathbin{\&} (u_i-1)\}$